# configuration issue with WolfSSL and ATECC508A

Tags: atmel, wolfssl, tls1.3

We are using the `ATECC508A` to support `WolfSSL` on a `Renesas RX600 CPU` (sorry - customer spec).  We are trying to do `TLS 1.3` on an IoT device.  Software `ECC` mode using `WolfSSL` - works fine.  `ATECC` hardware supported mode - fails with error -248 (`0xF4` in `cryptoauthlib`).
Traced the program in debugger down to the Pre-Master Secret step of the `TLS 1.3` handshake, where it fails doing a read from a slot of the `ATECC` chip.  We are using MicroChip's default provision configuration for `ATECC508A`.
It looks like the Pre-Master Secret is calculated using private keys internally, and gets returned by encrypted read from `ATECC` slot3.  However, the default `ATECC` configuration has slot 3 set to "Never Read" mode.  So, no surprise that it errors.

But, this is using default configuration of the `ATECC508A` slots, default setting from the `cryptoauthib` library, and unchanged code in `WolfSSL` (except for added debugs).  Am I missing something here?

**Versions:  WOlfSSL 4.0.0, CryptoAuthLib 20190304 Renesas RTOS RI600v4**

Any suggestions as to other things to look at?  I can provide `user_settings.h`, all the logs you could possibly want, etc.
Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Hi @Freedlight, I've asked the wolfSSL engineer that did the work on the ATECC508A/608A wolfSSL product to reach out if he has a chance. The ATECC508/608 product from wolfSSL is a solution for offloading ECC key operations to a Microchip (formerly Atmel) piece of hardware dedicated to ECC key management for users who are unfamiliar with the part and curious about this topic.

JFYI for best response times feel free to reach out to us at support@wolfssl.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original answer posted here: https://www.wolfssl.com/forums/topic1396-configuration-issue-with-wolfssl-and-atecc508a.html

Begin Quote

> The call to generate an ECC shared secret uses an encrypted channel
>   [which] requires a paired encryption key. The default wolfSSL examples
>   use `atmel_get_enc_key_default`, which is all 0xFF's. [One] should
>   override this function with [their] own implementation and key. This can
>   be done at build-time using `ATECC_GET_ENC_KEY`.
>
> If [one would] like to use a different slot for the ephemeral key generation
>   [the user] can override at build time with macro `ATECC_SLOT_ECDHE_PRIV` or
>   at runtime by registering a slot allocator using
>   `atmel_set_slot_allocator`. [A user] can test if its the encryption key by
>   replacing the `atcab_ecdh_enc` with `atcab_ecdh` in
>   `atmel_ecc_create_pms`.
>
> Also the ATECC chips have a watchdog that will occur if the chip isn't
>   put into idle state when done. [User will] notice calls to `atcab_idle`
>   in [] wolfcrypt/port/atmel/atmel.c to resolve this.
>
> Feel free to email [the wolfSSL support team] directly at
>   support@wolfssl.com with [] user_settings.h and logs.
>   These emails get directed [] to [the wolfSSL] ZenDesk
>   system and [one of our engineers will] make sure and grab the incoming ticket.
>
> Thanks,
>
> [D.G.], wolfSSL

End Quote

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that internally, WolfSSL calls out to atcab_ecdh_enc(), which intends to do an encrypted read from (slot+1).  The **default** configuration for the ATECC chip sets slot 3 sets this to never read.  WolfSSL suggests a configuration different from the MicroChip standard, which (ahem, cheap) companies like mine don't want to pay extra for.  So, it works with the ATECC configuration as WolfSSL specifies it, but does not work with the **default** configuration.

Our fix was to call atcab_ecdh() instead, which avoids the encrypted read, and passes the pre-master secret key back directly from the temp register.  This appears to work correctly (although I'm still testing).  MicroChip FAE assures me that this is not a security risk.

Thanks for the response.

Kit Taylor

Comment: it was a pleasure to assist on this and we are pleased to hear you found a resolution. Please let us know if anything else comes up, we are always happy to help out if we can! - the wolfSSL Support Team -